# Space wandering Mercenary looking to find Earth again

Tags: story-identification

Looking to find titles of series of books where the main character left Earth as a child for the galactic centre and became a mercenary but looking to find his way back to Earth. I read these circa 1978 - 1982
Characters name/s may be Earl or Drumminor , Drummond etc

Answer (score 8):

This is [E. C. Tubb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Charles_Tubb)'s [*Dumarest*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?1304) series, also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167765/identifying-a-finding-earth-series-of-scifi-novels) and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71683/identify-series-of-books-about-a-hero-chasing-a-body-switching-potion-between-pl).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumarest_saga):

> **Dumarest of Terra** is a 33-volume series of science fiction novels by [Edwin Charles Tubb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Charles_Tubb). Each story is a self-contained adventure, but throughout the series, Earl Dumarest, the protagonist, searches for clues to the location of his home world, Earth. Production of a television version of the series is set to begin in 2018.
>
> The stories are set in a far future galactic culture that is fragmented and without any central government. Dumarest was born on Earth, but had stowed away on a spaceship when he was a young boy and was caught. Although a stowaway discovered on a spaceship was typically ejected to space, the captain took pity on the boy and allowed him to work and travel on the ship. When the story opens in [*The Winds of Gath*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?2687), Dumarest has traveled so long and so far that he does not know how to return to his home planet and no-one has ever heard of it, other than as a myth or legend.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> Earl Dumarest, the protagonist of the series, is a galactic adventurer, sometime bodyguard, mercenary, gladiator, prospector, hunter, gambler and starship jack of all trades. Dumarest, as he is most often referred to in the books, is on a quest to return to the lost planet of his birth amongst the diverse and disparate worlds of the milky way galaxy. His home planet is Earth. In all of the books the notion of there being a planet called Earth is laughable to most of the people he meets, and for those who have heard the name, it is only as a myth from the deep past often referred to alongside gamblers' paradises such as Jackpot, Bonanza and the mythical El Dorado.

Comment: Beat me to it! :-)

Comment: In one of the books he finds a planet with a central computer that has all the information that he needs. The book is his attempt to get into the computer to find the data. Only at the end, after the revolution that he triggers destroys the computer data base does he discover that he could have gotten the answers to his questions by asking any *citizen* who all have unlimited access.